Is TCP not supported between Turn Server and peer by TURN server as per RFC 8656
I was going through these documentaion(https://www.100ms.live/blog/webrtc-turn-server#internal-working-of-a-turn-server) which is about how Turn server works and how to make one using CoTurn .
But in this section (https://www.100ms.live/blog/webrtc-turn-server#transport-protocols) it says that we cannot transfer with Client via TCP if a client has firewall on thats why it uses different protocols mentioned in the table . Also i observed in the table that sharing of data between Peer and Turn server is always UDP and this is mentioned in RFC 8656(https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8656#name-transports) . My question was What if there was a firewall attached to Peer would UDP work as Firewalls block all incoming UDP requests?
I was Expecting that Turn server might fallback to TCP or any other method

The reason this is not a concern is that the peer can also use TURN/TCP to talk to the TURN server. This gets them through the firewall.

But the table in RFC's link i have attached shows it always uses UDP for server to peer transfer

it does but that means it is using TCP -> UDP -> TCP overall

I dont get this TCP->UDP->TCP part can you please elaborate?

Both the client and the peer may use TURN/TCP to talk to their respective TURN server but those will use UDP to talk to each other.
